# How to get the Location in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, location-services

I am trying to use a `MVVM` design pattern and use a callback method to get the current Location into my View Model but I am not able to pass-back the Location value.

I have a pretty standard Interface that implements a `LocationListene`are here:

```
public interface MLBGameLocationListener extends LocationListener { }
```

In my Fragment, I am implementing the `MLBGameLocationListener` interface here:

```
public class MLBGameFragment implements MLBGameLocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        myViewModel.getGameLocation().set(location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude())
    }
}
```

I am setting the `gameLocation field in my`GameViewModel`, which is an`ObservableField``

I have a button in my Fragment that acts as a way to `getGameLocation()` the button is linked through my Fragment with this binding in my Text:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.getGameLocation()}"
```

I would like to access my `mViewModel.gameLocation` variable in my `getGameLocation` method and I would think it would be accessible because I am using implementing `onLocationChanged()`

I apologise for the novice question, I am just trying to understand the `MVVM` design and callbacks within Android.

Comment: On first glance looks a good question Darnold14, well done.

Comment: Is this sarcasm? Sorry, I am not great at this site.

Comment: The reason I need to do the Listener is that getLastLocation always returns null if I reinstall the APK.

Comment: No I don't do sarcasm, new user's are hard work, I'm nice and try my best to make people welcome (you may see some changes), I pushed hard to be nice to new users. I ranted and raved on the meta-stack...They did something...I cannot take credit. But i.c. where your coming from, hard nut to crack.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to solve my issue? Basically I just need a callback to my Location.

Comment: I'm a busy boy, but will help soon....see the star, your on my list...

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the help. It’s appreciated.

Comment: @Darnold14 what permissions have you added to the manifest file?